# DynamoDB: The provided key element does not match the schema

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb

I'm using nodejs and dynamoDB in a project. I'm having a problem whenever I try to get a device id but the error always appears: "ValidationException: The provided key element does not match the schema" in cmd.

DynamoDB:

[image]

My Code:
dynamo.js

[image]

app.js

[image]

ValidationException: The provided key element does not match the schema

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error probably happens from the `GetItem` operation (dynamoClient.get()) with the `Key` set to `{'id': id}`. There are two possibilities what your bug is (it's impossible to say more because your question is lacking a lot of information):

1. `id` is not the key of your item, or not the **whole** key. If your item key also has a sort key, not just a partition key, you must specify it as well. If you want to retrieve all the items with the same partition key with all sort keys, you must use a `Query` operation, not `GetItem`.
2. If `id` is indeed the sole key column, then maybe you are giving it the wrong type. It appears from the printout you included that `id` should be a number. If you pass it a string (I don't know what the "id" variable contains...) you'll get the error you mentioned.